# ¿Cómo se puede volver una caja de texto a una lista de texto?

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox

A la hora de que el usuario ingrese un texto en la caja de texto *TextBox*, y sean ciertos puntos, en este caso que sean similares a una lista *ListBox*. Quiero que todos estos datos ingresados, sean la cantidad **x** que sea, se vuelvan *listBox* y se guarden en este así se ingresen como *textBox*.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan ofrecer, porqué no tengo idea de como hacerlo .-.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Entiendo que queres ingresar un texto separado por /, lo queres convertir en un array para rellenar un listbox?

Answer (score 0):

Podes separar de esta forma las cadenas ingresadas en el `TextBox` y rellenar tu `ComboBox` con `List<string>`
El `Split` sirve para separar cadenas con caracteres específicos y de devuelve una arreglo.

```
        string texto = "La casa de papel / Dark / Control z";

        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        char s = '/';
        list.AddRange(texto.Split(s));
```